# List of usernames takes 5 minutes to show up on login screen after update to 23.10

Tags: login, gnome-shell, 23.10

After upgrading from 23.04 to 23.10 the list of usernames on the login screen take about five minutes to show up. Ctrl+alt+function keys don't give me a prompt during this time.

Afterwards the journal is filled with a few hundred thousand identical lines like this:

```
okt 16 19:28:29 mba-ubuntu gnome-shell[2255]: Attempting to call back into JSAPI during the sweeping phase of GC. This is most likely caused >
                                          The offending signal was g-properties-changed on GDBusProxy 0x559a9b5b4b10.
                                          == Stack trace for context 0x559a98c843f0 ==
                                          #0   559a98d4b8f8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/init.js:21 (35b912170ba0 @ 48)
```

I don't know the cause of the delay, but if I had to guess, I'd guess that.

How do I fix this? I have no pending updates. Should I reinstall some components? Which ones?

---

##### Update 1, systemd-analyze

Output of `systemd-analyze blame` as requested:

```
38.918s plymouth-quit-wait.service
 4.081s systemd-udev-settle.service
 3.504s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 2.600s zfs-load-module.service
 2.091s fwupd.service
 1.826s docker.service
 1.380s dev-sda3.device
 1.067s NetworkManager.service
  894ms snapd.service
  867ms apport.service
  782ms udisks2.service
  688ms accounts-daemon.service
  626ms iio-sensor-proxy.service
  620ms boot-efi.mount
  612ms power-profiles-daemon.service
  585ms polkit.service
  473ms e2scrub_reap.service
  459ms bluetooth.service
  455ms systemd-logind.service
  423ms upower.service
  407ms smbd.service
  365ms switcheroo-control.service
  351ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
  337ms nmbd.service
  335ms user@1000.service
  334ms containerd.service
  302ms gpu-manager.service
  290ms systemd-resolved.service
  282ms ModemManager.service
  274ms rsyslog.service
  268ms apparmor.service
  263ms systemd-udevd.service
  238ms snapd.seeded.service
  234ms keyboard-setup.service
  231ms systemd-journald.service
  223ms packagekit.service
  223ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
  212ms avahi-daemon.service
  210ms systemd-timesyncd.service
  209ms systemd-oomd.service
  201ms bolt.service
  181ms smartmontools.service
  161ms samba-ad-dc.service
  159ms update-notifier-download.service
  158ms dbus.service
  155ms systemd-modules-load.service
  153ms gdm.service
  140ms zfs-volume-wait.service
  135ms cups.service
  134ms modprobe@drm.service
  129ms thermald.service
  128ms snap-bare-5.mount
  126ms snap-code-142.mount
  124ms snap-code-143.mount
  121ms snap-core-16091.mount
  120ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-67E3\x2d17ED.service
  119ms snap-core-16202.mount
  116ms snap-core18-2785.mount
  114ms snap-core18-2790.mount
  111ms snap-core20-1974.mount
  110ms systemd-journal-flush.service
  110ms snap-core20-2015.mount
  107ms snap-core22-817.mount
  105ms snap-core22-864.mount
  102ms grub-common.service
  101ms snap-firefox-3252.mount
   99ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-140.mount
   96ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-143.mount
   96ms snapd.apparmor.service
   94ms snap-gnome\x2d42\x2d2204-132.mount
   91ms snap-gnome\x2d42\x2d2204-141.mount
   88ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1534.mount
   86ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount
   83ms snap-snap\x2dstore-1046.mount
   80ms snap-snap\x2dstore-959.mount
   78ms snap-snapd-20092.mount
   75ms snap-snapd-20290.mount
   72ms snap-youtube\x2ddl-4630.mount
   66ms systemd-sysusers.service
   65ms snap-youtube\x2ddl-4806.mount
   64ms systemd-rfkill.service
   64ms kerneloops.service
   61ms mnt-Windows.mount
   59ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
   57ms ubuntu-fan.service
   54ms systemd-binfmt.service
   54ms var-snap-firefox-common-host\x2dhunspell.mount
   53ms systemd-remount-fs.service
   50ms systemd-random-seed.service
   50ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
   46ms dev-loop10.device
   44ms dev-hugepages.mount
   43ms dev-mqueue.mount
   42ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
   40ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
   39ms docker.socket
   39ms colord.service
   39ms dev-loop13.device
   39ms dev-loop18.device
   39ms dev-loop12.device
   36ms dev-loop21.device
   36ms dev-loop14.device
   36ms dev-loop20.device
   36ms dev-loop17.device
   35ms dev-loop9.device
   35ms dev-loop8.device
   34ms kmod-static-nodes.service
   34ms modprobe@configfs.service
   34ms dev-loop11.device
   34ms dev-loop15.device
   33ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
   32ms systemd-sysctl.service
   32ms flatpak-system-helper.service
   31ms dev-loop16.device
   30ms systemd-update-utmp.service
   28ms dev-loop23.device
   28ms dev-loop19.device
   28ms modprobe@fuse.service
   26ms console-setup.service
   26ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
   26ms systemd-backlight@leds:smc::kbd_backlight.service
   25ms plymouth-read-write.service
   24ms plymouth-start.service
   24ms dev-loop22.device
   24ms alsa-restore.service
   21ms wpa_supplicant.service
   18ms ufw.service
   16ms systemd-user-sessions.service
   15ms snap.mount
   13ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
   12ms openvpn.service
   11ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
   10ms zfs-mount.service
   10ms zfs-share.service
   10ms sys-kernel-config.mount
    6ms modprobe@dm_mod.service
    6ms snapd.socket
    6ms modprobe@loop.service
    5ms modprobe@efi_pstore.service
    5ms rtkit-daemon.service
    4ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
    4ms setvtrgb.service
```

---

##### Update 2, journal

The problem seems related to the backlight OSD, judging by the first of 300,000 lines of gnome-shell warnings in the journal. I did have problems with the backlight OSD freezing when adjusting it below 60% before experiencing the problem described, and it seems they're connected (?) considering backlight is mentioned even after I stopped adjusting it.

```
okt 23 12:44:38 mba-ubuntu gnome-shell[1098]: Attempting to call back into JSAPI during the sweeping phase of GC. This is most likely caused by not destroying a Clutter actor or Gtk+ widget with ::destroy signals connected, but can also be caused by using the destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs. Because it would crash the application, it has been blocked and the JS callback not invoked.
                                              The offending signal was notify on Gjs_status_backlight_SliderItem 0x55faf54481a0.
                                              == Stack trace for context 0x55faf3327670 ==
                                              #0   7ffe7f1ec450 I   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/backlight.js:57 (1b0e2428e70 @ 131)
                                              #1   7ffe7f1ecfa0 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/GObject.js:687 (2ff9c29bec0 @ 25)
                                              #2   7ffe7f1ecfe0 I   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/backlight.js:197 (1b0e242c420 @ 199)
                                              #3   7ffe7f1ed010 I   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/backlight.js:157 (1b0e242c2e0 @ 12)
                                              #4   55faf33ef898 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/init.js:21 (2ff9c270ba0 @ 48)
okt 23 12:44:38 mba-ubuntu gnome-shell[1098]: Attempting to run a JS callback during garbage collection. This is most likely caused by destroying a Clutter actor or GTK widget with ::destroy signal connected, or using the destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs. Because it would crash the application, it has been blocked.
                                              The offending callback was AsyncReadyCallback().
                                              == Stack trace for context 0x55faf3327670 ==
                                              #0   55faf33ef898 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/init.js:21 (2ff9c270ba0 @ 48)
okt 23 12:44:38 mba-ubuntu gnome-shell[1098]: Attempting to call back into JSAPI during the sweeping phase of GC. This is most likely caused by not destroying a Clutter actor or Gtk+ widget with ::destroy signals connected, but can also be caused by using the destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs. Because it would crash the application, it has been blocked and the JS callback not invoked.
                                              The offending signal was g-properties-changed on GDBusProxy 0x55faf54439f0.
                                              == Stack trace for context 0x55faf3327670 ==
                                              #0   55faf33ef898 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/init.js:21 (2ff9c270ba0 @ 48)
okt 23 12:44:38 mba-ubuntu gnome-shell[1098]: Attempting to run a JS callback during garbage collection. This is most likely caused by destroying a Clutter actor or GTK widget with ::destroy signal connected, or using the destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs. Because it would crash the application, it has been blocked.
                                              The offending callback was AsyncReadyCallback().
                                              == Stack trace for context 0x55faf3327670 ==
                                              #0   55faf33ef898 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/init.js:21 (2ff9c270ba0 @ 48)
okt 23 12:44:38 mba-ubuntu gnome-shell[1098]: Attempting to call back into JSAPI during the sweeping phase of GC. This is most likely caused by not destroying a Clutter actor or Gtk+ widget with ::destroy signals connected, but can also be caused by using the destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs. Because it would crash the application, it has been blocked and the JS callback not invoked.
                                              The offending signal was g-properties-changed on GDBusProxy 0x55faf54439f0.
                                              == Stack trace for context 0x55faf3327670 ==
                                              #0   55faf33ef898 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/init.js:21 (2ff9c270ba0 @ 48)


...
```

Comment: What does `systemd-analyze blame` say?

Comment: @kanehekili I attached the output

Comment: @kanehekili That's most likely not a boot issue but rather a gnome-shell i.e. userspace issue ... Andreas this is most likely caused by a GUI app especially Gnome extension that is not compatible (*not handling signals properly*) with the new updated Gnome version ... Do you have any Gnome extensions installed? try disabling them.

Comment: @Raffa Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I believe so; I'm too used to all of them disabling themselves in every upgrade to to have thought they'd cause trouble after one.

Comment: @Raffa Update: disabled all extensions not listed as built-in, but no luck. Still a five minute wait on login.

Comment: It's a [Gnome thing](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gio/stable/GDBusProxy.html#GDBusProxy-g-properties-changed) anyways ... So, I would focus on that ... It could be some other GUI related app(*[GTK related](https://docs.gtk.org/gio/signal.DBusProxy.g-properties-changed.html)*) or even a bug although  a bug is the least probable in this situation.

Comment: I might be wrong, but plymouth-wait depends on GDM (or any DisplayManager) , so I'd also check the GDM logs.

Comment: @Raffa That's about as far as I got, reading the 300 000 lines of `gnome-shell` warnings in the journal. How many GUI related apps are there on the login screen? Anyway, I've had indications that it's the backlight brightness OSD, since it froze when dropping below 60%, but the problem persisted even when I stopped adjusting it. It's still mentioned in the journal though...

Comment: @kanehekili I updated the question. I'm speculating it's to do with the backlight adjustment OSD, which is accessible on the login screen. Any concrete suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems to have done the trick (after concluding that there were no separate packages that handled backlight GUI, etc) was:

```
apt reinstall gnome-shell
dpkg-reconfigure gnome-shell
```

I doubt the second command did it but I threw it in for good measure, which is easier than to actually look up what it does, considering that even its man-page can't be bothered to explain its purpose (I mean: "dpkg-reconfigure reconfigures packages" -- wow, thanks, everything's clear to me now...)

Answer (score 0):

I just fought the same issue and I was able to fix it by setting the keyboard backlight to 0 from the terminal. I found it using:

```
find /sys -name '*backlight*'
```

There will likely be a few matches. In my case, I remembered that I recently increased it using the fn keys and tried the one that looked most like the one, and set it using:

```
echo 0 > /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/17761776:00/leds/system76_acpi::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

Maybe this helps somebody save some time.